# Unable to start search indexer on Sitecore 10 after upgrading from Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: upgrade

Started upgrading from `Sitecore 9.0.2` to `Sitecore 10`.

In the post upgrade steps, when I restart the indexing worked process, it throws the error below

[image]

I redid the steps again and again from the guide but it pauses at this error.
I am using `solr 8.11.1` and is hosted on port 8984

Comment: wrong config. most probably still something from 9.0.2. compare your configs with configs from 10